# install package in kaggle

Tags: python, kaggle

i have tried to istall pyrdf2vec in kaggle:

```
!pip insatll pyrdf2vec
```

and this error appears:

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7cfc7bf64220>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/pyrdf2vec/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7cfc7bf64550>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/pyrdf2vec/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7cfc7bf647f0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/pyrdf2vec/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7cfc7bf649a0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/pyrdf2vec/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7cfc7bf64b50>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/pyrdf2vec/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyrdf2vec (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyrdf2vec
add Codeadd Markdown
```

!pip insatll pyrdf2vec

```
and this error appears:
```

WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7cfc7bf64220>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/pyrdf2vec/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7cfc7bf64550>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/pyrdf2vec/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7cfc7bf647f0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/pyrdf2vec/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7cfc7bf649a0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/pyrdf2vec/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7cfc7bf64b50>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/pyrdf2vec/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyrdf2vec (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyrdf2vec
add Codeadd Markdown